# How to add byte[] attachment in draft using mailkit in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mailkit

`public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }` is attachment which I want to add in 
 draft save. Anyone has the idea how to save `byte[]` in a draft attachment?

```
public void DraftMessage(string strto, string strcc, string strBcc,
     string strSubject, string strBody, List<UserAttachment> listAttachments)
{
    try
    {
        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage();
        email.MessageId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
        var list = new InternetAddressList();

        if (strto != "")
        {
            string[] strArrayto = strto.Split(';');

            if (strArrayto != null)
            {
                list = new InternetAddressList();

                foreach (string _strTo in strArrayto)
                    list.Add(new MailboxAddress(_strTo));

                email.To.AddRange(list);
            }
        }

        if (strcc != "")
        {
            string[] strArraycc = strcc.Split(';');

            if (strArraycc != null)
            {
                list = new InternetAddressList();

                foreach (string _strcc in strArraycc)
                    list.Add(new MailboxAddress(_strcc));

                email.Cc.AddRange(list);
            }
        }

        if (strBcc != "")
        {
            string[] strArrayBcc = strBcc.Split(';');

            if (strArrayBcc != null)
            {
                list = new InternetAddressList();

                foreach (string _strBcc in strArrayBcc)
                    list.Add(new MailboxAddress(_strBcc));

                email.Bcc.AddRange(list);
            }
        }

        email.Subject = strSubject;
        email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
        {
            Text = strBody
        };

        SaveMessgeSummary(email, strDraftfolder, listAttachments);

        var draftFolder = MailManager.Instance.ImapClient.GetFolder(strDraftfolder);

        if (draftFolder != null)
        {
            draftFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

            draftFolder.Append(email, MessageFlags.Draft);
            draftFolder.Expunge();
        }

        DAL.MessageSummary.UpdateExecutStatus(email.MessageId);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Above code I am passing parameter `List<UserAttachment> listAttachments` which is using below class:

```
public class UserAttachment
{
    public byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
    public string strFileName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#CreateAttachments) explains how to create an attachment.

Comment: It is a good source of information, but I want to pass byte[] in the attachment. Also what to do if you want to add multiple attachments in the same mail.

Comment: Just add another one to the `multipart`?

Comment: How to add byte[] in the attachment?

Comment: Convert it to a stream. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#CreateAttachments) explains how to create an attachment:

```
var attachment = new MimePart ("image", "gif") {
    Content = new MimeContent (File.OpenRead (path), ContentEncoding.Default),
    ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition (ContentDisposition.Attachment),
    ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
    FileName = Path.GetFileName (path)
};
```

The `MimeContent` type accepts a `Stream` and you can convert a `byte[]` to a `Stream` by creating a `MemoryStream`:

```
Content = new MimeContent (new MemoryStream(byteArray), ContentEncoding.Default),
```

Comment: And will the MemoryStream be closed after the message is sent, or I should take care of closing stream myself ?

Comment: @DotNetFan There isn't any documentation about it. It seems you should always [close the streams that you open](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/issues/444). But `MemoryStream` may not use unmanaged memory so you might [not need to dispose of it at all](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream#remarks).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an attachment with your e-mail, Visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/590638/net-core-5-web-api-email-attachment-using-mimekit I have implemented it easly.